# pseudo class nth-of-type not applicable on specific class

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

On the first time my HTML,CSS looks perfect, but as shown in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c45tf/1/), when clicking on button, I want to hide/show some `.show` elements. When I hide them, CSS is broken. I dont know what I am missing.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="show">box</span>
    <span class="show">box</span>
    <span class="show">box</span>
    <span class="show">box</span>
    <span class="show">box</span>
    <span class="show">box</span>
    <span class="show">box</span>
    <span class="show">box</span>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="click" />
```

CSS:

```
div .show:nth-of-type(-n+4) {
    margin-top:0;
}
div .show:nth-of-type(4n) {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $("span:eq(0),span:eq(2)").toggle().toggleClass("show");
});
```

[**Jsfiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/c45tf/1/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is this your real case, or is it a simplified case to show the issue? Because if it is the real case, then you can forget about the nth-of-type styles, and just adjust the padding top and right of the container...

Comment: @vals no this is simplified case. actual case is complex

Comment: @Hiral Hi i got same problem but unable to solve by this below answer can u help me to solve my problem..

Comment: @DhavalPanchal can you show sample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `:nth-of-type` will not count only the `.show` elements, it will count *all* `spans`. So when you hide some of them, even though they're hidden, they still count.

If you're going to show and hide the spans, `nth-of-type` probably isn't what you need.

I'm not a CSS wizard. Two options come to me:

1. Don't hide the elements, `detach` them, and then reattach them later. Then they aren't in the parent anymore and `:nth-of-type` will keep working. See the example below.
2. (And I don't like this, but...) Don't use `:nth-of-type`, use classes you assign via JavaScript whenever you show/hide spans (basically running through the visible ones and giving them classes to do what you need.)

Here's an example of doing the detach/reattach thing: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c45tf/3/)

```
// Get the spans
var $spans = $("#container span");

// Assign them indexes
$spans.each(function(index) {
    this.setAttribute("data-index", index);
});

// Attach/detach on a toggle
var detached;

$("#button").click(function () {
    if (detached) {
        reattach(detached);
        detached = undefined;
    }
    else {
        detached = detach();
    }
});

function detach() {
    var rnd1, rnd2;

    // Pick two at random
    rnd1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * $spans.length);
    do {
        rnd2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * $spans.length);
    }
    while (rnd2 === rnd1);

    // Detach them
    return $("#container span:eq(" + rnd1 + "),span:eq(" + rnd2 + ")").detach();
}

function reattach(spans) {
    spans.each(function() {
        var $span = $(this),
            index = +$span.attr("data-index");
        if (index === 0) {
            $span.prependTo("#container");
        }
        else {
            $span.insertAfter($spans[index - 1]);
        }
    });
}
```

Note that it's important that the `div` containing the spans *not* have an empty text node as its first child (your fiddle does, I've removed it in mine). That's because when we put the spans back, since we always do them in order, if we're reattaching the first one we have to use `prependTo` rather than `insertAfter`, and the text node messes things up.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: Stock them in a variable and remove them from the DOM ?

Comment: Why not use `:nth` instead of `:nth-of-type`?

Comment: @Hiral: I added a `detach` example. Just the easy part (detaching). I'll leave the slightly-harder part (reattaching, which is only slightly-harder because you have to remember where they go) and the classes solution to you. :-)

Comment: @Hiral: I got to wondering how hard it would be to reattach them in the right places, and it wasn't hard at all. I've updated the answer.